When was the world's minimum rate of forced labour?
According to the International Labour Organization (ILO) the rate of forced labour globally is currently going up:
Definition of forced labor

Forced labour, as set out in the ILO Forced Labour Convention, 1930 (No.29),1 refers to “all work or service which is exacted from any person under the menace of any penalty and for which the said person has not offered himself voluntarily.”  ILO

status quo

[In 2022] There are 27.6 million people in situations of forced labour on any given day.
Forced labour has grown in recent years.
A simple comparison with the 2016 global estimates indicates an increase of 2.7 million in the number people in forced labour between 2016 and 2021, which translates to a rise in the prevalence of forced labour from 3.4 to 3.5 per thousand people in the world. The increase in the number of people in forced labour was driven entirely by forced labour in the private economy, both in forced commercial sexual exploitation and in forced labour in other sectors.

history
Looking further back, their estimates have grown even more dramatically, though they note the difference in methodology means that those changes at least do not necessarily accurately reflect true changes in the world:

2012 Global estimate of forced labour
20.9 million people are victims of forced labour globally
Results and methodology
In 2005, the International Labour Office (ILO) published its first global estimate of forced labour. The estimate (a minimum of 12.3 million persons in forced labour at any point in time in the period 1995-2004)
Given the changes made in the methodology and the greater quantity and quality of data available for the present round of estimation, the numerical results of the 2012 estimation are not comparable to those derived in 2005.

Presumably there was a time in the past where the rate of global slavery was higher than it is now.  Can we say when in history the global rate of forced labour was the lowest?

First step (IMHO) is "how far back does the ILO extend analysis?"  What's the gap between the end of (US ) slavery and the start of the ILO? How reliable are the estimates for that gap?    This is a complex question.

@MCW Note "In 2005, the ILO published its first global estimate of forced labour"

You are looking for the minimum rate, meaning the proportion of the total population, not the absolute number, correct? (that seems like the better question seeing the dramatic increase in total population in the last few hundred years.

@quarague That is what I mean, and I think I am specific about that in the answer.
